Proof that the second fundamental form vanishes in a direction, when a line in that direction is contained in a surface
Proof that the second fundamental form vanishes when a line is contained in a surface
I am working on a problem in differential geometry and would appreciate some help.
Problem: Consider a surface $\Sigma$, a point $p \in \Sigma$, and a vector $u \in T_p\Sigma$. Suppose the line $p + \mathbb{R}u$ lies entirely within the surface $\Sigma$. How can we prove that the second fundamental form at $p$, denoted by $\text{II}_p(u)$, satisfies $\text{II}_p(u) = 0$?
I understand that the second fundamental form is related to the curvature of the surface, but I am struggling to connect this with the given condition about the line being contained in $\Sigma$.
Any hints, explanations, or references would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

You should either accept the answer I wrote several days ago or else ask some follow-up questions if you are not satisfied.

Your title and text are highly confusing (title subsequently revised). The second fundamental form does not vanish. You are saying that the normal curvature in the direction of the line vanishes. The most immediate proof is this: Letting $n$ denote the surface normal and $\alpha$ a parametrization of the line with $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=u$, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{II}(u) &= -dn_p(u)\cdot u = -dn_p(\alpha'(0))\cdot\alpha'(0) = -(n\circ\alpha)'(0)\cdot\alpha'(0)\\ &= (n\circ\alpha)(0)\cdot\alpha''(0)=0.
\end{align*}
At the last step we use $(n\circ \alpha)(t)\cdot \alpha'(t)=0$ for all $t$ and differentiate.
By the way, if your text states Meusnier's Theorem, it is an immediate consequence of that.
